# Word wrapping for the Android autosized TextView

Tags: textview, android-support-library, android

I want to have TextView with the autosized text as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html).
I`ve supposed, the word "Testing" should be aligned on the single line, but it is wrapped character-based (see "g" on another line).
How should I change my configuration so everything will work as I desire?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Autosizing starts unfortunately after whole text can't fit into TextView. Since you allow maximum of 3 lines autosizing will start after text can't fit in 3 lines or it's height is bigger than defined. Right now I am struggling with same issue and I don't see any other solution than to try implementing custom word wrapping mechanism, but I have no idea how to do it at this point :).

So just to answer your question, you can simply change maxLines="1" and it will work as desired.